# How do I route 2 diffrent audio inputs to 2 audio outputs

Tags: sound, 20.04

So I have 2 different audio inputs (aux), one from my mic which I want to use like a mic and the second from my other PC which I want to route to my headset. I attempted to use pulseaudio, mixxx and jack. anyone know how to do this easily?